# emoji in hyper terminal for windows

Tags: windows, macos, terminal, emoji, hyper

I am new to windows and previously used to work on mac, I am starting to hit a roadblock that is - I am unable to see emojis in windows hyper terminal or even the command prompt, any way we could render emojis
 [screenshot of hyper terminal in windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PLNg.png)

which was supposed to look like this

[screenshot of hyper terminal in mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCeq0.png)

what I feel is that I might be missing something, please do let me know.